# How to bind a button that open jPlayer in fullscren mode

Tags: jplayer

How to bind a button that open jPlayer in fullscren mode ?

I have a custom user button in my html:

```
 <a onClick="javascript:$('#top_video_player').jPlayer('fullScreen');event.preventDefault();" class="button" href="#">Open in big Screen</a>
```

But this don't work.

I also try:

```
$('#top_video_player').jPlayer('option','fullScreen',true)
```

or

```
$('#top_video_player').jPlayer('option',{fullScreen:true})
```

also try to add class .jp-full-screen to my  button ( tag ) - no effect too ):

But failed again - nothing happened

In my jPlayer initialization i bind it to "enter" button and it works - but i also need to bind another html button:

```
keyBindings: {
                play: {
                    key: 32, // space
                    fn: function(f) {
                        if(f.status.paused) {
                            f.play();
                        } else {
                            f.pause();
                        }
                    }
                },
                fullScreen: {
                    key: 13, // enter
                    fn: function(f) {
                        if(f.status.video || f.options.audioFullScreen) {
                            f._setOption("fullScreen", !f.options.fullScreen);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it by using:

$('#top_video').data('jPlayer')._setOption('fullScreen', true);

where 'top_video' - jplayer div id